# Automating the search results with all the items in the result with specific color

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, specflow

I have a search scenario for a clothing retailing site.

Using Specflow framework (C#) and Selenium.

I Need to automate the Search widget and its results.

1) The search widget yields results of different types : Name of item , partial text , type of dress

2) Also it yields result by color of the product , i.e. if the product has a specific color available , it would give me in the result.

EG:  If i have typed "blue" in the search widghet , It would yield me all the products/items which has blue inside or say available.

3)  Issue is the color is available only in the product detail page and not product search page. Product search page only gives you the net result of the products in list form where theres image of the product, product name, price etc.

4) How to automate such a scenario that i verify that all the products listed does have that specific attribute or say blue color without going into product detail page.

Comment: Inspect the Markup and See the attribute associate to each Item, there must be some kind of class or other attribute associated with the color, then you can match / bind all items with that attribute

Comment: @Zach : Sorry but can you provide me with a code , would appreciate the help.

Comment: @ArpanBuch If you want code as an answer it helps if you provide code in the question, otherwise you are likely to find that you just get generic answers to a generic question. Do you have anything you can post here?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you may have already answered your own question, but lets break down what you are trying to do here. The scenario you have is simply

```
When i enter "blue" it should return me back all the items/clothes which is blue
```

This implies to me that you are testing many different parts of your system with an acceptance level test that covers

- database connectivity/authorisation
- query building
- results deserialization/model conversion into viewable form (ViewModel)
- building of a list/thumbnail view in the UI

Also you've used the word `all` in your scenario so that implies that we need to actually test *two* things

- All the results that came back include the colour blue, and
- *There are no additional results for blue that haven't been returned*

**All the results that came back include the colour blue**

You could write a function that takes the item/clothing and checks it fields to make sure one of them contains blue, but then you are falling into the put of writing parallel test code. Consider this problem code

```
select * from Items
where tags like '%blue%'
or description like '%blue%

public void IsBlue(Item item)
{
  return item.Tags.Contains("blue") || item.Description.Contains("blue");
}
```

As your code changes you have to keep rewriting your tests to make them pass.

Unfortunately the only way to *reliably* test that the user sees something that is blue, is to show what they will see. If your list/thumbnail view doesn't include blue, then you have to navigate to the details page and check that. What you really want is something simple like

```
IsTrue(DetailsPage.Html.ToString().Contains("blue", CaseInsensitive));
```

**There are no additional results for blue that haven't been returned**

In some ways this is even harder to achieve. Once again we could replicate the querying but that leads to

```
if (GetAllBlueThingsFromDb() == GetAllBlueThingsFromDb()) ....
```

A better way is to work with a known database that is reset back to its default state after every tests run.

```
public const int NumberOfBlueThingsInTestDb = 42;
if (GetAllBlueThingsFromDb() == NumberOfBlueThingsInTestDb) ....
```

Comment: +1 good point about checking for the extra blue items that have not been returned by the search

Answer (score 0):

your only option, if the search results do not provide the information needed, is to further query to get that information. You tagged this specflow so having your steps would be useful, but assuming that you steps look something like this:

```
When i enter "blue" and search
Then all the items/clothes in the results are blue
```

you can then implement your then step something like this (pseudo code):

```
foreach(var result in searchResults)
{
    if (GetItemColour(result)!=Colours.Blue)
    {
         Assert.Fail("Non blue item returned: " + result);
    }
}

private Colour GetItemColour(SaerchResult result)
{
   //navigate to item description page for given item
   //or call some API to get item details for given search result id
   // then return the colour from that page
}
```

Comment: Seems legit. Will have to try on the logic given by u. lets see if it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, the snippet below should give you an idea of how to go about doing it

```
//Locator is a custom class created with methods such as hasClass, getElement
//Instead of an Element you should consider using something like a 
//List<WebElement> that returns list of elements.


 public boolean hasClass(String className) {

     return webElement  != null && 
                        ((WebElement) webElement).getAttribute("class").contains(className);
 }

 Locator locator = Locator.by(by);

 if(locator.hasClass("colorBlue")) {
     Assert.assertTrue;
 } else {
    Assert.Fail( "No Items with color");
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem with this is that the OP already said that they don't have any information about the colour returned in the search results. Your suggestion will work well for finding the details if they exist, but they don't exist in the search results at the moment so something else must be done to get them